# Reset Default Workbook Open options

Tags: excel, vba

I use VBA in Excel to pull data from different sources (mostly .csv and .xls/.xlsx files) and paste them into my data tables (in the same Excel File I have a data table for each specific data source).

Each of those files comes with different settings. I have created an specific VBA Macro for each of my data sources to process, remove and copy the relevant information of each individual file, and then I call all of the Macros from another Macro. The problem I'm having is that for one of the data sources, when using the `Workbooks.Open` method, I have had to set the parameter Format to "Nothing" (`Format:=5`). But this affects then the subsequent macros and therefore the following files are not processed correctly.

I know I have two possibilities: Either I call this macro at the end, after I've processed all the other files or; I set the Format parameter in all of my Macros to the one specific for each of the files configuration. However there must be a way to simply reset the delimiter to the default one used in my Regional Settings. Does anyone knows a solution?

Sorry if there's already a thread with this issue but I've tried looking for it and didn't find any.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is exactly the problem with delimiter? If it is anything affecting the formulas then check difference between Formula and FormulaLocal. First one is universal and alwais is stored in this format, the second one is a local representation of the first one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulalocal and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply @armagedescu. The specific problem with this data source is that, If I use simply `Workbook.Open`, the default delimiter will apply automatically. But before it does that, I need to do some changes to the file. I have to find and replace certain strings that create issues when trying to split the text into columns. The only solution I've found so far is to set parameter `Format` of the `Workbook.Open` method to Nothing, then I can perform the find/replace operations and then I use `TextToColumn` method, to separate correctly the info into columns.

Comment: Did it solve your issue?

Comment: Always helps to post your actual code...

Comment: Hi @armagedescu. The issue is not related to Formula or FormulaLocal. Is directly related with setting the Format parameter of the Workbook.Open method to Nothing. I'm trying to manipulate the Regional Settings to go back to the default separators. But the `Application.International` property is Read only and stating `Application.UseSystemSeparators = True` at the end of my Macro to try to reset the default settings, doesn't work either. At the end I had to specify the Format parameter of the Workbook.Open method in all my macros and that did the trick. But there must be a simpler way.

Comment: @LeonardoCamejoMartínez Please check the previous comment from Tim Williams. Also, if you care about separators it means you do something wrong. Excel does not care about separators internally because it uses a system independent format. The separators are used only to show visually in some format. But not to store information.